# How can I prove that $x-{x^2\over2}<\ln(1+x)$

Tags: inequality, logarithms, taylor-expansion

How can I prove that $$\displaystyle x-\frac {x^2} 2 < \ln(1+x)$$ for any $x>0$

I think it's somehow related to Taylor expansion of natural logarithm, when:

$$\displaystyle \ln(1+x)=\color{red}{x-\frac {x^2}2}+\frac {x^3}3 -\cdots$$

Can you please show me how? Thanks.

Comment: It's false. Consider $x = 0$.

Comment: @GFauxPas I forgot to insert x>0

Comment: You can't use the Taylor series, by the way, because the series only works for $-1 < x \le 1$

Comment: @GFauxPas, Why the Taylor series does not work for $x > 1$?

Comment: @AlexSilva Use the ratio test: we need $\displaystyle \left \vert {\frac {x^{n+1}}{n+1}\frac{n}{x^n} } \right\vert < 1$

Comment: Related (duplicate?): http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/105281/proving-the-inequality-x-x2-2-ln1x-x-x0

Comment: @GFauxPas, thanks!:)

Comment: This question is also related, although it contains an upper bound, too: [Proving inequality on functions $x-\frac{x^2}{2}<\ln(1+x)<x-\frac{x^2}{2(1+x)}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/171659)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:

Prove that $\ln(1 + x) - x + \dfrac{x^2}2$ is strictly increasing for $x > 0$.

edit: to see why this isn't a complete proof, consider $x^2 - 1$ for $x > 0$. It's strictly increasing; does that show that $x^2 > 1$? I hope not, because it's not true!

Comment: So if it's strictly increasing then the inequality $ln(1+x)-x+{x^x\over 2}>0$, is true for any x, thus the relation is proven. So ?

Comment: Almost. There's one more step.

Comment: Do I have to note that $x>-1$, from logarithm ?

Comment: So what's the last step ? It's seems complete to me

Comment: You have to plug in $x = 0$ too

Comment: @Zarrax Why do I have to plug in zero if I've already proven that the inequality holds for any $x>0$ ?

Comment: I understand may be,so..(wait please), So , in this case with $x^2-1$ I observed that for x between 0 and 1 , and 1 is a solution of $x^2-1$, the function is negative, but for 1 to infinity its positive, so I think I have to equal the expression $ln(1+x)-...$ to zero, to see what are the solutions. The only solution is zero, so for any x>0 the inequality is true. This means that there are surely no intervals included in x>0  for which the function is negative.  So?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "solution", but you're saying good things :)

Comment: So this the final proof, is it ?

Comment: @GFauxPas Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

consider $f(x)=\ln(1+x)-x+\dfrac{x^2}{2}$

$f^{'}(x)=\dfrac{x^2}{1+x}>0$ forall $x>0$

Hence f(x)>f(0)