# Let $k\in\Bbb{N}$. Prove that $0<\frac{1}{k}-\ln(1+\frac{1}{k})<\frac{1}{2k^2}$

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, logarithms

Not sure how to approach it, tried with basic algebraic manipulation but got no where. We are learning Mean Value Theorem and Taylor's Theorem so I would believe maybe we use one of those two theorems, or it may be another method. Need a hint starting it.

Comment: See also: [Prove inequality $0< \frac{1}{n} \ -\ln\left( 1+\frac{1}{n} \right) < \frac{1}{2n^{2}}$ using Taylor polynomial](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3521341) and [How can I prove that $x-{x^2\over2}<\ln(1+x)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1110508).

Answer (score 2):

**HINT**

By $\frac 1k =x$ we need to show that

$$0<x-\ln(1+x)<\frac{1}{2}x^2 \iff x-\frac12x^2\le \ln(1+x)\le x \quad x\in(0,1]$$

Answer (score 2):

You can use the Taylor series for $\log (1+x)$ to get 
$$\ln\left(1+\frac 1k\right)=\frac 1k-\frac 1{2k^2}+\frac 1{3k^3}-\frac1{4k^4}+\ldots$$
Now apply the alternating series theorem which says if you truncate the alternating series the error is smaller than and of the same sign as the first neglected term.

Answer (score 2):

**Further Hint:** The inequality [suggested by gimusi](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3005582/let-k-in-bbbn-prove-that-0-frac1k-ln1-frac1k-frac12k2/3005588#3005588) $$x-\frac{1}{2}x^2\leq \ln(1+x)\leq x\text{ for }x\geq 0$$
can be proven via Taylor's Theorem or via the inequality
$$1-x\leq \frac{1}{1+x}\leq 1\text{ for }x\geq 0\,.$$

Comment: Thanks for the quote. Yes I would suggest the simpler second way by derivatives.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:  $\ln\left(1+\frac1k \right)=\int_k^{k+1}\frac1x dx$

Also on $[k,k+1]$ we have $\frac1{k+1} \le \frac1x \le \frac1k $, with strict inequality over most of the interval.

Then since the interval is of length $1$, we have 
$$ \frac1{k+1} <\int_k^{k+1}\frac1x dx <\frac1k $$
So
$$ \frac1{k+1} <\ln\left( 1+\frac1k\right) <\frac1k $$
Then see if you can manipulate this inequality to what you need.

Answer (score 1):

Let
$$
x_n=\left(1+\frac 1n\right)^n
$$
It's well known that $x_n$ is strictly crescent and converges to $e$. Then
$$
\left(1+\frac 1k\right)^k<e\Rightarrow k\ln\left(1+\frac 1k\right) < 1\Rightarrow \frac 1k - \ln\left(1+\frac 1k\right) > 0
$$

Consider now the function
$$
f(x)=\frac 1{2x^2}-\frac 1x + \ln\left(1+\frac 1x\right)
$$
then
$$
f'(x)=-\frac 1{x^3} +\frac 1{x^2} -\frac 1{x(x+1)}=\frac{-x-1+x^2+x-x^2}{x^3(x+1)}<0
$$
so $f$ is strictly decreasing then

$$
f(n)>\lim_{x\rightarrow +\infty}f(x)=0\Leftrightarrow \frac 1{2x^2}>\frac 1k-\ln\left(1+\frac 1k\right)
$$

Answer (score 0):

$$ \log(1+\tfrac{1}{k})=\log(k+1)-\log(k)=\int_{k}^{k+1}\frac{dx}{x}=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{dx}{x+k} \tag{1}$$

$$ \tfrac{1}{k}-\log\left(1+\tfrac{1}{k}\right)=\int_{0}^{1}\left[\frac{1}{k}-\frac{1}{x+k}\right]\,dx=\frac{1}{k}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{x}{x+k}\,dx\tag{2} $$

$$ \frac{1}{k}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{x}{x+k}\,dx \leq \frac{1}{k}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{x}{k}\,dx = \frac{1}{2k^2}.\tag{3} $$

Improving the approximation through the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality:

$$ \tfrac{1}{k}-\log\left(1+\tfrac{1}{k}\right)\approx \frac{1}{k}\sqrt{\int_{0}^{1}x\,dx\int_{0}^{1}\frac{x\,dx }{(x+k)^2}}=\tfrac{1}{k\sqrt{2}}\sqrt{\log\left(1+\tfrac{1}{k}\right)-\tfrac{1}{k+1}} $$
we get:
$$ \log\left(1+\frac{1}{k}\right)\approx \frac{1+k(5+4k)-\sqrt{(1+k)(1+9k)}}{4k^2(1+k)}.\tag{4}$$
This is very accurate for large values of $k$ and acceptable for $k\approx 1$. For instance, the error of $\log(2)\approx\frac{5-\sqrt{5}}{4}$ got by setting $k=1$ is not much larger than $2\cdot 10^{-3}$.