# Prove $\ln(1+x)\geq x-\frac{x^2}{2}$

Tags: calculus, derivatives, inequality, logarithms, taylor-expansion

> When $x\geq0$ prove that: 
>   $$\ln(1+x)\geq x-\frac{x^2}{2}.$$

**My effort:** From the Taylor series:

$$\ln(1+x)= x-\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^3}{3}-\cdots$$

I don't know how to continue from here.

Comment: Hint: use Taylor’s theorem with the remainder

Comment: If the remainder term is negative on the interval, then the sum of the zeroth through $n^{th}$ order terms yields an upper bound.

Comment: you have a mistake in the Taylor development.

Comment: @user48672 fixed it. Does it deserve a vote up now?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews for $x\geq 0$ man. Thanks a lot.

Comment: See also: [How can I prove that $x-{x^2\over2}<\ln(1+x)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1110508). Found [using Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Cln(1%2Bx)%5Cgeq%20x-%5Cfrac%7Bx%5E2%7D%7B2%7D%24&p=1)

Comment: This question is also related, although it contains an upper bound, too: [Proving inequality on functions $x-\frac{x^2}{2}<\ln(1+x)<x-\frac{x^2}{2(1+x)}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/171659)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Let $f(x)=\ln(1+x)-x+\frac{x^2}{2}$.

Thus, $$f'(x)=\frac{1}{x+1}-1+x=\frac{x^2}{1+x}\geq0.$$

Thus, $f(x)\geq f(0)=0$ and we are done!

Answer (score 14):

Observe that $$\ln(1+x) = \int_0^{x} \frac{1}{1+t}dt.$$
But, for $t \ge 0$, $$\frac{1}{1+t} \ge 1-t.$$
Therefore,
$$\ln(1+x) \ge \int_{0}^x(1-t)dt=x-\frac{x^2}{2}.$$

Comment: I was looking for an integral proof, but missed this. :)

Comment: $\frac{1}{1+t}\ge 1-t$, where $t\in\mathbb R$, is true if and only if $t>-1$. But in this case we only need $t\ge 0$ because the definite integral is over $t\in [0,x]$.

Answer (score 6):

You want to show $$1+x\geq e^{x-x^2/2}$$

or $e^{x^2/2}(1+x)\geq e^{x}.$

The right side is $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^k}{k!}$ and the left side is:

$$(1+x)\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^{2j}}{2^jj!}=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^{k}}{2^{\lfloor k/2\rfloor}\lfloor k/2\rfloor!}$$

But $2^{\lfloor k/2\rfloor}\lfloor k/2\rfloor!\leq k!$.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint**

$$f(x)=\ln(1+x)-x+\frac{x^2}{2}$$

so,

$$f'(x)=\frac{1}{1+x}+x-1=\frac{x^2}{x+1}>0 \text{ for } x> -1$$

Answer (score 2):

You want to prove $\ln(1+x)\ge x-\frac{x^2}{2}$ for all $x\ge 0$.

To prove it for $0\le x<1$, we'll use Taylor series. It converges because $-1<x\le 1$. [See, e.g., here for more information.](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_logarithm#Derivative.2C_Taylor_series) Or [here](https://www.google.lt/search?dcr=0&source=hp&ei=F4e8WdnrL6ad6ATg0pT4AQ&q=ln%281%2Bx%29+converge&oq=ln%281%2Bx%29+converge&gs_l=mobile-gws-hp.3..0i22i30k1l5.1177.7871.0.8290.18.17.1.0.0.0.154.1976.1j15.16.0....0...1.1j4.64.mobile-gws-hp..1.17.1990.3..0j35i39k1j0i131k1j0i67k1j0i30k1.225.PEX2wU5iMZE).

$$\ln(1+x)=x-\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^3}{3}-\frac{x^4}{4}+\cdots$$

$\ln(1+x)\ge x-\frac{x^2}{2}$ is equivalent to $\frac{x^3}{3}-\frac{x^4}{4}+\cdots\ge 0$.

We'll prove for all $k\ge 3$, $k\in\mathbb Z$, $\frac{x^k}{k}-\frac{x^{k+1}}{k+1}\ge 0$. We could prove this using derivatives, but I'll use a simpler method here. The inequality is equivalent to

$\frac{x^k(k+1-kx)}{k(k+1)}\ge 0$

and we have

$\frac{k+1}{k}>1> x$, $x^k\ge 0$ because $x\ge 0$.

Using derivatives:

Proof: let $f(x)=(k+1)x^k-kx^{k+1}$.

Then $f'(x)=k(k+1)x^{k-1}(1-x)\ge 0$.

$f(x)\ge f(0)=0$.

Also notice that $\left(\frac{x^3}{3}-\frac{x^4}{4}\right)+\frac{x^5}{5}\ge 0$, where also $\frac{x^5}{5}\ge 0$, $\frac{x^{2t+1}}{2t+1}\ge 0$ for all $t\ge 2$, $t\in\mathbb Z$.

Therefore, if $0\le x<1$, then $\frac{x^3}{3}-\frac{x^4}{4}+\cdots \ge 0$, i.e. $\ln(1+x)\ge x-\frac{x^2}{2}$.

By the way, notice that when finding the sum $\frac{x^3}{3}-\frac{x^4}{4}+\cdots$, you have to find the limit of partial sums so that you have to sum the terms in the exact same order $\frac{x^3}{3}$, $\frac{x^3}{3}-\frac{x^4}{4}$, $\frac{x^3}{3}-\frac{x^4}{4}+\frac{x^5}{5}$, etc. because [see the Riemann series theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_series_theorem): summing the terms in a different order could result in a different number or diverge if the series is conditionally convergent. But in this case, $\frac{x^3}{3}-\frac{x^4}{4}+\cdots$ is not conditionally convergent when $-1<x<1$, because if $-1<x<1$, then it converges to $\ln(1+x)-x+\frac{x^2}{2}$ and $\frac{x^3}{3}+\frac{x^4}{4}+\cdots$ converges to $-\ln(1-x)-x-\frac{x^2}{2}$.

Here's a proof for $x\ge 1$. If $x>1$, then the Taylor series diverges, so we can't use it. $$x-\frac{x^2}{2}=\frac{2x-x^2}{2}=\frac{1}{2}-\frac{(x-1)^2}{2}\le $$

$$\le \frac{1}{2}<\ln 2=\ln(1+1)\le \ln(1+x)$$

because $1=\ln e<\ln 4=\ln 2^2$, i.e. $1<2\ln 2$, because $e<4$ and $\ln x$ is strictly increasing when $x>0$.

Answer (score 0):

There is an easy way to prove. Note that
$$ (1+t)(1-t)=1-t^2\le 1 $$
and hence
$$ \frac{1}{1+t}\ge1-t. $$
Integrating from $0$ to $x$, one has
$$ \int_0^x\frac{1}{1+t}dt\ge\int_0^x(1-t)dt $$
which gives
$$ \ln(1+x)\ge x-\frac12x^2. $$

Comment: $\frac{1}{1+t}\ge 1-t$ is true if and only if $t>-1$, but we only need $t\ge 0$. Also, this exact same proof has already been posted as an answer here.

Comment: @user263326, I did not realize that someone already posted.