# Integral of Integral part times Fractional part

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series

Let $I$ be defined as
$$I=\displaystyle\int_0^1\Big\lfloor\frac1x\Big\rfloor\Big\{\frac1x\Big\}dx$$
I found that
$$I=\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^\infty\left(k\ln\left(\frac{k+1}{k}\right)-\frac{k}{k+1}\right)$$
which I'm not sure if converges or not. Any thoughts??

Comment: $\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^\infty\left(k\ln\left(\frac{k+1}{k}\right)-\frac{k}{k+1}\right)$ does not converge.

Comment: $\{z\}$ is not the *"decimal part"* because it does not depend on the base of the representation you are using.  Better term is *"fractional part"*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For $0 < x \le 1$ is
$$
 \ln (1+x) = x - \frac 12 x^2 + \frac 13 x^3 - \frac 14 x^4 + \cdots
$$
an alternating series with terms of decreasing magnitude, and therefore
$$
 \ln (1+x) > x - \frac 12 x^2 \, .
$$
(Actually that inequality holds [for all $x > 0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2417934/42969), but we don't need that here.)

It follows that
$$
k\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{k}\right)-\frac{k}{k+1} \ge k \left(\frac 1k - \frac{1}{2k^2}\right) -\frac{k}{k+1} = \frac{k-1}{2k(k+1)} \sim \frac{1}{2k}
$$
for $k \to \infty$, so that the series and the integral are divergent.

Answer (score 0):

We can also apply the integral test to prove divergence. The function $xln(1+\frac{1}{x})-\frac{x}{x+1}$ is strictly decreasing for x>N and the indefinite integral (using integration by parts) is I=$\frac{1}{2}x^{2}ln(1+\frac{1}{x})-\frac{x}{2}+\frac{ln(x+1)}{2}$.But the first term is approximate to $\frac{1}{2}e^{x}$ which implies that the integral diverges as $x\to +\infty$ !